# C++ std::bind usage error: compilation failure?

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

I've got the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
void f(int &i,int &j){
    ++i;
    ++j;
}
int main(){
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    bind(&f,_1,ref(i))(3);
    bind(&f,ref(j),_1)(4);
    return 0;
}
```

clang --std=c++11 gives following error:

```
no matching function for call to object of type '__bind<void (*)(int &,
  int &), std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &, int &>'
bind(&f,_1,i)();
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Stop `using namespace std`.

Comment: and `f` is....?

Comment: The functor produced by `bind` expects one argument (seeing as you've used `_1` in it). You are calling it with none. It's not clear what you expected to happen. You have function `f` taking two parameters (if the error message is to be believed; the declaration of `f` is conspicuously absent from your example). Which two arguments do you want it to be called with?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Just edited my question. Please check again.